# Access map elements in a vector in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector, stdmap

Is it possible to access the elements in a `map` without iterating through the `for(std::map<std::string, double>::iterator it = elem.begin(); it != elem.end(); ++it)` loop?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, int>> v;
    for (auto ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
    {
        std::map<std::string, int> _map;
        _map["type"] = ii;
        v.push_back(_map);
    }
    
    for(auto elem : v)
    {
       std::cout << elem["type"];
       for(std::map<std::string, int>::iterator it = elem.begin(); it != elem.end(); ++it)
       {
           std::cout << " Keys: " << it->first << std::endl;
       }
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0 Keys: type
1 Keys: type
2 Keys: type
```

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that, C++ doesn't work this way. The shown code doesn't even iterate over each map in the vector, it makes a complete temporary copy of each map in the vector, and iterates over the duplicate copy.

Comment: You access a map via iterator or via key lookup. You code does both, so either you already understand that, you don't understand the code you wrote, or you don't understand the code someone else wrote. I'm unclear what the issue is. Is it possible to access pairs in a map without using iteration? Sure. Use a key lookup. If you don't have the key to do that, what other option were you looking for *besides* iteration or key lookup?

Comment: I was wondering whether it is possible to access a map without iterating. For example, to have something like vector.at(i) get the key (if unknown) instead of vector.at(i)["key"].

Answer (score 2):

It is possible in a less verbose way:

```cpp
    std::map<std::string, int> m;
    m["t1"]=1;
    m["t2"]=2;
    m["t3"]=3;

    for(auto pair: m){
        std::cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: (note: `auto pair` make a temporary copy of each pair. To access the original pairs in the map, use `auto&`. To stop yourself editing the original pairs in the map by mistake, use `auto const&`)

Comment: @user253751 it would have been something like `for (auto const& elem : v)` and `for( auto const& [key, val] : elem )`. Thanks!